# Protoc protoc-gen-go "timestamp" is not defined

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I need to use Protocol Buffers to serialize JSON messages received from the Google Drive drives:list method and write them to the BigQuery Storage Write API (GRPC).  This is working for all field types except timestamp.  I cannot for the life of me generate go classes that include timestamps.  To begin, I'm following [this document](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/), although have also tried everything I can find online including here on stackoverflow to no avail.

On MacOS 12.6, protoc is installed from [this zip](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v21.6/protoc-21.6-osx-aarch_64.zip) to /usr/local/bin and the contents of include from the zip are installed to /usr/local/include.

This is the drives.proto file I need to create a class for:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option go_package = "./driveBuffers";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
message Drive {
  string id =1;
  string name =2;
  string colorRgb = 3;
  string backgroundImageLink =4;
  bool hidden = 5;
  string orgUnitId = 6;
  timestamp createdTime = 7;
  message restrictions {
    bool adminManagedRestrictions = 1;
    bool domainUsersOnly = 2;
    bool copyRequiresWriterPermission = 3;
    bool driveMembersOnly = 4;
  }
}
```

If I remove the field with type timestamp, the tool creates a file named ./driveBuffers/drives.pb.go.  With the timestamp type, this error is thrown:

```
% protoc --go_out=. -I ./ -I /usr/local/include/ drives.proto
drives.proto:11:3: "timestamp" is not defined.
```

Thank you.

Comment: you need to stick with types defined in [this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#scalar) document. There isn't a timestamp type there.

Comment: if you are using [this](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto) file to get a timestamp field, you need to use it as `Timestamp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refer the type as `google.protobuf.Timestamp`. As example:

```
  string orgUnitId = 6;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp createdTime = 7;
```